# webpack dev server routing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react app and have just installed react router to get some routing going. I am importing react router like so:

```
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';
```

Here is the code I have implemented to render the routes:

```
var routes = (
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}/>
      <Route path = "/test" component = {Test}/>
   </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(
   routes
   ,document.getElementById('main')
);
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/test I get an error saying `Cannot GET /test`.

After looking online for a possible solution all I could find was adding `historyApiFallback: true` to my webpack.config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './scripts/main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

Still no joy so not sure what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try adding `contentBase` in your `devServer` so it can load the right html file, example `devServer: {
  contentBase: './public',
    historyApiFallback: true
  }`

Comment: tried and no joy im afraid

Comment: which server are you for the frontend? `Express`? `webpack-dev-server`?,`historyApiFallback` will only work if you're using `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: im using webpack-dev-server

Comment: from the directory where `webpack` config file is located, Whats the `path` of the directory where the `html` file you want to serve located?

Comment: same directory @RandomUser

Comment: then set `contentBase` to `contentBase: './'`

Comment: Yes I already tried that but no luck

Comment: Try changing `historyApiFallback` to `historyApiFallback: { index: 'index.html' }`

Comment: still no joy @RandomUser

Comment: worth noting if I change browserHistory to hashHistory it works fine as a hash URL

Comment: Yes that's because its `hashHistory` can you take a screenshot of your project directory or upload list of all files/folders in your project dir so i can see its structure?

Comment: let me know if this is enough: http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=14_untitled609.png

Comment: can you upload codes of current `webpack` config and `index.html` files?

Comment: webpack: https://jsfiddle.net/0yfc2bya/  index: https://jsfiddle.net/65jka52b/

Comment: Just wondering, when you goto `http://localhost:8080` you see the app right? or the error?

Comment: I see the app no problem

Comment: Here's the packages I have installed @RandomUser :https://jsfiddle.net/zjv9fwk7/ .Its worth noting I have history installed but im not calling it anywhere in main.js

Comment: Wait a min.. how do you run/start the server?

Comment: using Cmder I type webpack-dev-server --progress --colors

Comment: Did you restart server after making changes? I did a local setup with your config/code but its working fine for me.

Comment: That was it @RandomUser ...how frustrating. Do you want ot post the answer? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, but it's not uncommon.. most of the times, its the simple mistakes we make that frustrate us a lot. We both learnt something basic and will not forget it anytime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all the discussion we had in comments,

The answer is

Did you **restart** the server after making changes?